# Voltage at AREF pin

Tags: arduino-uno, analogreference, voltage-divider

I find difficulties to measure correctly the voltage at the AREF pin.
I would measure voltages ‭with a resolution not exceeding 1 mV . nda voltage divider 
In one of my trials, I was using a  9V battery and a voltage divider made with a 1k resistor and a 2k one.

[image]

The battery voltage was about 8890 mV and the reference voltage was about 2960 mV (confirmed by a multimeter).
I  connected the output of the divider to the AREF pin of an Arduino Uno board. The output voltage value dropped to about 1800 mV. Reading the voltage value at AREF pin with a simple sketch:.

[image]

the serial monitor printed:

[image]

as if the voltage dividere did not exist.
What am I doing wrong? or what I don’t understand?
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: analogRead(EXTERNAL)? EXTERNAL s 0. you read A0

Comment: On the AREF pin you provide a reference voltage that is compared with the voltage you will measure on the Ax pins. AREF is not a Ax pin. You can not measure it directly with `analogRead(EXTERNAL)`  but you can connect AREF to e.g A0. But as VREF is the reference you compare A0 with the result would always be 1023. The Voltage you measured on the VREF pin is lower than  you measured on the unconnected voltage divider because VREF has a low impedance and changes the  voltage divider.

Comment: One solution to stabilize the voltage divider is to use a Zener diode with a reverse breakdown voltage of 3V (or what ever you need for AREF) instead of the R2 resistor. The arrow/triangle of the Z-Diode  must face towards the R1. You can not measure the AREF with the same Arduino because AREF is the reference of the measurement, its result would always be 1023, if you measure the reference itselfe .

Comment: You could also build a stabilized voltage source with a LM317. And you should consider using the 5V of the Arduino to create the reference voltage from. (As long as you need about 3V that's no problem). Then you get rid of the 9v batterie.

Comment: Very clear and detailed. Thanks.Paolo

Answer (score 2):

> I was using a 9V battery and a voltage divider made with a 1k resistor and a 2k one.

Using a battery is not a good way of getting a stable voltage. A battery's voltage will change over time.

Using a voltage divider is not a good way of generating a reliable stable voltage. The output impedance is very high and will be affected by any loading you apply to it causing it to droop.

If you want 1mV per LSB then you need a 1024mV voltage reference (since there are 10 bits of resolution, or 1024 possible divisions, in the ADC). For that you want a 1024mV voltage reference, which is a standard value for precision voltage reference chips such as the LM4140CCM-1.0/NOPB from Texas Instruments. Personally I like to use a precision DAC like the MCP4821 to provide a settable analog reference voltage.

> Reading the voltage value at AREF pin with a simple sketch the serial monitor printed 8890 as if the voltage dividere did not exist. What am I doing wrong?

You cannot read anything from the AREF pin. It is merely a voltage reference, not an active pin you can read. When you use `analogRead(EXTERNAL)` you are actually doing `analogRead(0)` since `EXTERNAL` is a macro that expands to `0`. That means you are really reading from pin A0 not the AREF pin.  And then you just map that to 8890 when it's at maximum anyway. Since A0 is (probably, since you don't show anything else in your circuit) floating it will most likely be above the voltage you are feeding in to AREF and will return 1023 all the time anyway.